# Validation for Select elements of React-Bootstrap are mis-aligned

Tags: css, reactjs, validation, react-bootstrap

I'm using React-Bootstrap (note: we're on the relatively new v1.0.0 !)

I can add validation to my forms rather nicely, but it doesn't play well with Select dropdowns:

> [image]

**How do I fix this?**
Is the only option to figure what manual css to layer onto the Controls, to re-locate the validation icons?

Code:

```
  <Form validated>
    <Form.Group>
      <Form.Label>Text Input</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control required type="text" value="foo"/>
    </Form.Group>
    <Form.Group>
      <Form.Label>Invalid Dropdown Input</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control required as="select" value={''}>
        <option key={'empty'} value={''}>...</option>
        <option key={'1'} value={'1'}>1</option>
        <option key={'2'} value={'2'}>2</option>
      </Form.Control>
    </Form.Group>
    <Form.Group>
      <Form.Label>Valid Dropdown Input</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control required as="select" value={'2'}>
        <option key={'empty'} value={''}>...</option>
        <option key={'1'} value={'1'}>1</option>
        <option key={'2'} value={'2'}>2</option>
      </Form.Control>
    </Form.Group>
  </Form>
```

Comment: Opened as a library Issue on GitHub: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/3495

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can add ***custom*** attr to ***Form.Control***

Please find below code snippet for your reference

Notice **custom** attr in <Form.Control required as="select" custom>

```
<Form.Control required as="select" custom>
   <option value="">...</option>
</Form.Control>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by wrapping the input with a label.